# How to compare a slice with a vector in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do I compare an array slice with a vector in Rust? The code in question:

```
fn parse<R: io::Read>(reader: R, fixed: &[u8]) -> io::Result<bool> {
    let mut buf = vec![0; fixed.len()];
    match reader.read(&mut buf) {
        Ok(n) => Ok(n == fixed.len() && fixed == &mut buf),
        Err(e) => Err(e)
    }
}
```

The error that I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8]: std::cmp::PartialEq<std::vec::Vec<u8>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:32:47
   |
32 |         Ok(n) => Ok(n == fixed.len() && fixed == &mut buf),
   |                                               ^^ can't compare `[u8]` with `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<std::vec::Vec<u8>>` is not implemented for `[u8]`
```

The answer must be simple but it is eluding me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error message states:

> the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq<std::vec::Vec<u8>>` is not implemented for `[u8]`

However, the [opposite direction *is* implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-PartialEq%3C%26%27b%20%5BB%5D%3E):

```
Ok(n) => Ok(n == fixed.len() && buf == fixed),
```

---

Additionally, you will need to mark your parameter as mutable: `mut reader: R`.

[`Read::read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) performs the `n == fixed.len()` check for you.

Allocating a vector full of zeroes is not as efficient as it could be. You could instead limit the input and read into a vector, allocating as you go:

```
fn parse<R>(reader: R, fixed: &[u8]) -> io::Result<bool>
where
    R: Read,
{
    let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(fixed.len());
    reader
        .take(fixed.len() as u64)
        .read_to_end(&mut buf)
        .map(|_| buf == fixed)
}
```

The implementation of equality for slices already compares the lengths of the two sides, so I've also removed that, while switching to using combinators.

Comment: `n == fixed.len()` is redundant with `read_to_end`, since `n` always equals `buf.len()` and `buf == fixed` must compare the lengths of the slices first.

Comment: @trentcl a partial read would mean that `buf.len()` is shorter, but yeah, the equality check does the length anyway.

Comment: However, it took me long enough to confirm that that it might be better just to leave the check in rather than make assumptions. :)